# Kohana Query Builder support for DATEDIFF?

Tags: sql, mysql, kohana-3

According to this: http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/database/builder#limitations Kohana doesn't support parentheses in database queries. How can I get around this to add this to my query:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(`date`, $today) = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DB::expr` or use double quotes:

```
$query->where('DATEDIFF("date", '.$today.')", '=', 0);
```

Note that `$today` must be validated or escaped before using it!

Comment: As of v3.0.10, you'll also be able to do this: `->where('DATEDIFF("date", :today)', '=', 0)` with `->param(':today', $today)` to have the value of "today" automatically quoted.

Comment: I found using the ->param(':today', $today) very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
  $this->qualifiers[] = array(DB::expr("DATEDIFF(`date`, '$today')"),'=',0);
```